# How to append subset dataframes to a separate dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iteration

I am trying to append dataframe subsets to a separate dataframe.

So far I have tried append to an empty dataframe, but it returns an empty dataframe.

```
search_ID = ['36962G3P7', 'B3V3W13', 'XS1903485800', 'EXLS']

Search_Results = pd.DataFrame()    
for i in search_ID:    
    current_table = df.loc[df.isin([i]).any(axis=1)]
    Search_Results.append(current_table)

#Returns an empty dataframe
```

When I print every iteration it shows that it is creating new dataframes for every list item.

```
Search_ID = ['36962G3P7', 'B3V3W13', 'XS1903485800', 'EXLS']

Search_Results = pd.DataFrame()    
for i in Search_ID:    
     current_table = df.loc[df.isin([i]).any(axis=1)]
     print(current_table)

 #Returns 4 printed dataframes
```

When I append outside the loop, the table does append to the empty dataframe.

```
current_table = df.loc[df.isin(['36962G3P7']).any(axis=1)]
Search_Results.append(current_table)

#Returns a filled dataframe
```

Comment: The append method does not modify the caller dataframe. You must do `Search_Results = Search_Results.append(current_table)` to assign the result of the append operation to `Search_Results`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The append function does not occur in place, so you need to reassign on each iteration.

```
Search_Results = Search_Results.append(current_table)
```

Depending on how many times you append, this can be very slow so you might instead consider:

```
Search_ID = ['36962G3P7', 'B3V3W13', 'XS1903485800', 'EXLS']

Search_Results = pd.concat([
    df.loc[df.isin([i]).any(axis=1)]
    for i in Search_ID
], axis=0)
```